# What are the rational characters of $GL(n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am referring to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714138/one-dimensional-representations-of-gln-k) avout the characters of $GL(n)$. We know that characters (in the sense morphisms to $\mathbb{C}^\times$) of $GL(n)$ factorize by the determinant.

However, I am interested by *rational characters*. How to determine the rational characters of $GL(n)$? Are they only those given by polynomials in the determinant? (we know these are indeed polynomials, i.e. rational, but how do we know they are the only ones?)

I am in particular interested in seeing it is a *lattice*, since we often talk about the lattice of rational characters.

And what about $SL(2)$? Are they all trivial because the determinant is trivial there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume by "rational character" you're referring to group homomorphisms $f \colon \mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{C}^n) \to \mathbb{C}^*$ which are given by rational functions of the coordinates of the matrices. These correspond to the 1-dimensional rational representations of $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{C}^n)$. They are $A \mapsto \det(A)^k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$--see any book that describes the irreducible rational representations of $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ (I learned from Fulton's *Young Tableaux*). I do not know what you're referring to concerning a lattice.

As Fulton notes in the discussion following Theorem 2 on page 114, the story for $\mathrm{SL}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is the same except the determinant representation is now trivial.

Comment: $\det(A/\det(A))=\det(A)^{1-n}$. Over an algebraically closed field $[GL(n),GL(n)]= SL(n)$  so that $[SL(n),SL(n)]=SL(n)$. On the other hand $GL(2,\Bbb{F}_2)=SL(2,\Bbb{F}_2)$ and $[GL(2,\Bbb{F}_2),GL(2,\Bbb{F}_2)]$ has index $2$ and there is a non-trivial character given by a polynomial, but it isn't a morphism of algebraic variety.

Comment: Why are you noting $\det(A/\det(A)) = \det(A)^{1-n}$?

Comment: $\det(c I) = c^n$ not $c$ so $A/\det(A)$ is not in $SL(n)$ in general

Comment: How silly of me, thanks, updated.